# Text Qualifiers for column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below in MYSQL.

```
ID     Name
1      aaaa
2      bbbb
3      cccc
```

I want to store the data (with aText Quqlifier ") the below format in database.

```
ID     Name
1      "aaaa"
2      "bbbb"
3      "cccc"
```

How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Tablename (Name) values ('"aaaa"'),('"bbbb"')
```

or

```
UPDATE Tablename SET name=concat('"',name,'"');
```

Comment: your quotes are unbalanced

Comment: Thanks for notifying @Felix

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` SET `my_field`='"aaaa"'
```